# New to it... what does "business demand" mean in Tiny Tower?

Tags: tiny-tower

In the game "Tiny Tower" if you click on "menu" and then click on "stats" it will show "retail" , "creative" , "food", etc.

Below the graphs there are percentages, and above the graphs it says "business demand".

What does that mean? Does it mean something like the lower the number the more of that item I need? Or the less I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buisness Demand is the demand for specific floor types.

An article on Floor Types can be found [**here**](http://tinytower.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Floor_Types).

We have all the floor types, as shown below:

- Creative
- Food
- Recreational
- Residential
- Retail
- Service

Lets say, that I have 60 creative floors and **none** of the others.

My demand would say, that no-one wants anymore creative floors (because theres too many!) and want ALOT of everything else.

Demand and supply. The more you have, the less they want it. The less you have, the more they want it. And so on, so forth.

It is not based off of **how many items** certain shops have, it is the **amount** of **floors** you have.